# Backward comparability

Tags: c#

If I have a function that was return an int LoadProgress(int), now the same function is changed but it will break other game projects, because now it takes returns a keypairvalue, but I mistakenly I removed the original function which takes int lodprogress(int), is it ok to add the same function but with different input and output?

There are also function that saves and load from the files that will break the other game projects, how would I ensure the backward compatibility

Comment: Hi can you please specify your question better, so we may understand you and help you? :) Show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This borders on too broad / unclear. More detail is needed to answer your specific questions.

> is it ok to add the same function but with different input and output?

Yes, but the return type isn't part of the signature, i.e. a class containing two methods only differing in return type won't compile.

> how would I ensure the backward compatibility [in] function[s] that save and load the files

Again, you need to show the code and explain what you want to change in order for this to be properly answered, but optional parameters may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If the new method has another signature than the old method, it is fine.

These don't conflict for example, their signature differ in type:

```
public void DoThis(int oldParameter) { }
public void DoThis(string newParameter) { }
```

These do, since the return type isn't part of the signature:

```
public void DoThis(int oldParameter) { }
public int DoThis(int newParameter) { }
```

There is nothing present for backwards compatibility on that level. You can't just mix old and new together without loading the old in a different `AppDomain`. Just think twice before you create something, and adapt your old code to fit the new where needed.

Answer (score 0):

The method name is not sufficient to identify a method.

Both its name, its return type and its arguments type defines the method.

Basically: `void Foo(int)` is different than `void Foo(string)` or `int Foo()`.

When several methods have the same name, these are considered as overloads and the compiler will choose the correct one depending on the argument you are passing.

In your case, if the old method should not be used, excepted from legacy code you don't want to rewrite, I suggest you to use the [`Obsolete` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx). This will help developers to identifies deprecated methods by generating a warning at compile time (or even a compile error if you set the flag):

```
[Obsolete("Please use the 'void Foo(int, string)' overload"]
void Foo(int a){
    // old code
}

void Foo(int a, string b) {
    // new code
}
```

Comment: The return type is not part of the signature.